# Стилизация точки маршрута Yandex.Maps API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

имею совсем не замысловатый код, использующий Yandex.Maps API, маршрут строю так:

```js
ymaps
  .route([coords1, coords2], {
    mapStateAutoApply: true,
  })
  .then((route) => {
    this.route = route;

    route.getPaths().options.set({
      strokeColor: '2CC37C',
      opacity: 0.9,
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(route);
  });
```

Как бы я мог теперь стилизировать вот эти точки на карте (задать другой заголовок, а не "1", "2", другую картинку маркера, цвета и так далее), которые указаны на скриншоте? Пишу данный вопрос от отчаяния, так как облазив документацию несколько часов, так и не нашел решения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/router/multiRouter.html#multiRouter__how-to-build-route) из документации, правда тут используется [MultiRoute](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute.html)

```
var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [
        "Москва, Ленинский проспект",
        "Москва, Льва Толстого, 16",
        "Москва, метро Водный стадион"
    ]
}, {
    // Задание внешнего вида начальной точки.
    wayPointStartIconLayout: "default#image",
    wayPointStartIconImageHref: "images/myImageStart.png",
    wayPointStartIconImageSize: [10, 10],
    wayPointStartIconImageOffset: [-5, -5],
    // Задание внешнего вида конечной точки.
    wayPointFinishIconLayout: "default#image",
    wayPointFinishIconImageHref: "images/myImageFinish.png",
    wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [10, 10],
    wayPointFinishIconImageOffset: [-5, -5],
    // Задание внешнего вида промежуточной путевой точки.
    wayPointIconLayout: "default#image",
    wayPointIconImageHref: "images/myImageWayPoint.png",
    wayPointIconImageSize: [10, 10],
    wayPointIconImageOffset: [-5, -5],
    boundsAutoApply: true
});

// Добавление маршрута на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
```

Про стилизацию меток тоже можно глянуть в [доке](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geoobjects.html#geoobjects__icon-style).